# Nuxt js / Vuex Cannot get state variables on components which is set by nuxtServerInit

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, state, vuex

I am trying to get the state variable on components which is set by the nuxtServerInit Axios by get method.

store/state.js

```js
export default () => ({
  siteData: null
})
```

store/mutations.js

```js
import initialState from './state'

const mutations = {
  SET_SITE_DATA (state, value) {
    state.siteData = {
      site_title: value.site_title,
      logo: value.logo
    }
  }
}

export default {
  ...mutations
}
```

store/getters.js

```js
const getters = {
  siteDetails: state => state.siteData
}

export default {
  ...getters
}
```

store/actions.js

```js
const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit ({ commit, dispatch }, ctx) {
      try {
        const host = ctx.req.headers.host
        const res = await this.$axios.post('/vendors/oauth/domain/configuration', { domain: host })
        commit('SET_SITE_DATA', res.data.data.site_data)
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    },
  
  export default {
    ...actions
  }
}
```

store/index.js

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import mutations from './mutations'
import getters from './getters'
import actions from './actions'
import state from './state'

const store = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
  })
}

export default store
```

Here I set `SET_SITE_DATA` mutation which set `siteData` state.

components/Header.vue

```html
<template>
  <section class="header sticky-top">
    <client-only>
      {{ siteDetails }}
      {{ $store.getters }}
      { logo }}
    </client-only>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['siteDetails']),
    logo () {
      console.log(this.$store.state.siteData)
      return this.$store.state.siteData
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Console

[image]

I don't know what is happening here. You can see I have consoled the values. So when I reload the page I can get the values but after few seconds all values reset to the null. I want to set those values globally so can access them all over the site. I don't want to call API every time a page changes so I used `nuxtServerInit` so can set values globally when the page reloads once and can access them.

Comment: "So when I reload the page I can get the values but after few seconds all values reset to the null", isn't because your client side code overrides the server side values?

Comment: How can handle this? because I want to call API on time to set those values and don't want to modify it.

Comment: Are you overriding the values at some point? Maybe try to look if the value already exist before mutating it? (aka check if falsy and define then)

Comment: Yes, I can console values. I get first time and 2nd time it shows null

Comment: I added console result